# Unmetaing strip cancels cuts

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Assume I insert one movie strip inside the sequencer, I have one video track and one audio track. Since I want to keep only a subsequence of this strip, I meta the audio and video track and then cut this meta strip to keep only the part that I want. Once this is performed, I would like to retrieve both the audio and video track independently, so I unmeta the meta strip, but this gave me back the total audio and video tracks, as if the cut that I performed on the meta strip was not taken into account.

Is there any solution for what I want to do? Obviously, I don't want to perform the cut on both the audio and video tracks separately.

Many thanks,

Blender 2.77 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I don't have a hard answer but as far as I know it isn't possible. There are some pretty good-looking and free addons related to the vse that let you trim clips before adding into the vse among other things. Check out http://easy-logging.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this add-on, it seems handy. However if I understood correctly, it only allows to set an in and an out point for a given clip. Ideally, what I would like is to import several subsequences of a clip, i.e. set several in and out points, I don't think it's possible with this addon unfortunately. But thanks anyway, if you have any other recommendation, don't hesitate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, meta strips always keep the content as it is.

If you want to cut both audio and video at the same time, you can use the select linked time mode to select them both. **It only works if the audio and the video strips are the same length**. If they aren't, just cut the extra footage on the longer strip, and it'll work. By default, it's done by pressing Ctrl + Select Mouse (Ctrl Right Click).

Then you just have to cut like usual.

[image: Select strip with linked time]

This keymap item can be found under Sequencer / Sequencer (Global)

[image: Sequencer global keymap]

Comment: Yes that's also the solution I came up with in the end, thanks anyway for your reply!